# trying to accesing images stored on Ubuntu server directory gives 403 forbidden

Tags: tomcat, access-denied, ubuntu-server

I am developing an application in which I have to store images in a directory on a Ubuntu 16.04 server. These images will be served as a static content across the application. I have added following in Tomcat `server.xml` file:

```
<Context docBase="/home/ubuntu/images" path="/APPlicationName/images"/>
```

To try to server the images. The problem is if I try to access the images from a browser like http://example.com:port/ApplicationName/images/image.png, I am getting access forbidden. Any suggestions?

Comment: Forget to add the text  i have added Context tag in server.xml and brovided a docbase with a path

Comment: Is the `APPlicationName` a typo or does it really have capital *APP* at the start of the URI? If so, you must use http://example.com:port/APPlicationNme/images". Also, have you checked the permissions of `/home/ubuntu/images`?

Comment: Thanks . there was issue with the permission